# How to feed normalized new data to saved trained neural network model and then inverse the result?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I am working on a research population by country based on this data set:
https://www.kaggle.com/tanuprabhu/population-by-country-2020

I learned that it's best practice to normalize the dataset before training, so I normalized the data using sklearn.preprocessing MinMaxScaler. I proceeded to train the model using the normalized dataset before saving the model.

Next, I wanted to perform predictions on new data. So I created an input file with a similar format to the training dataset. The new input data has only 2 rows (versus the training dataset which has 200 rows).

The problem that I encounter is, due to a small number of data in the new dataset, the minmaxscaler returned 1 and 0. 1 is for the bigger number, and 0 for the smaller number. When I feed this input into the model, it gave me a prediction that is too far off from the expected value.

I have also tried to apply mixmaxscaler to the new data, feed into the model, and then inverse the result. Still, I got a value that is too far from the expected value.

I have also tried to train the model without applying mixmaxscalar. I got a better result in this model, but the predicted result only respond very well when I changed certain columns with bigger values. The columns with smaller values don't have a very good response, while in real world I know that this factor is quite significant to the predicted result.

Where do I went wrong?
Any sample code on handling the input for the trained model is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ or even https://ai.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: The small (or large...) number of samples in the new dataset should play absolutely no role in scaling, except if you do the mistake of re-fitting your scaler in the new data instead of using the already fitted scaler to transform them. This is not at all apparent (there is good reason why we ask for code, instead of such verbal descriptions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test what is going on I suggest that you take a row of your training data prior to scaling it. Apply the scalar and then use the result as the data for a prediction. You should get the same predicted result as the train data result value. When you apply the scalar look to see if it generates the same values as present in the training data for that row. Make sure you are using the scalar that was fit to the training set. Do not fit the scalar to the new data, just use it to transform the data.

Comment: Thank you soo much Gerry for pointing on my error. I have managed to solve this problem. The lesson learned is, for training, I should use 'fit_transform'. Later, for input into model, I should use 'transform'. Use 'inverse_transform if necessary

Comment: glad to help. If you want to learn more there are some excellent videos you may find useful at https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLs_CQl4mUvI7Z9HnwoeOS5EUu9gyvekjK.